# Can a GUI component get the GUI editor snap-to-grid value?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-xe2

Delphi's form editor snaps controls to a grid. Can a component get the snap grid size at design time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read it from the registry. It's in `HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\10.0\Form Design` (substitute `CodeGear` or `Borland` and `5.0`, `8.0`, etc.) for the version you're using. The Grid size is available in `Grid Size X` and `Grid Size Y`, and whether or not `SnapToGrid` is enabled in `Snap To Grid`.

Comment: `Inprise` was never used as a Registry key name, but `Borland` and `CodeGear` were.  Also, the product name may be `Delphi`, `C++Builder`, or `BDS`. So you would need to adjust the key name based on which version of which specific IDE you are targetting: `Borland\Delphi\#.#` for Delphi 2-8, `Borland\C++Builder\#.#` for C++ 1-6, `Borland\BDS\#.#` for Delphi 9-11 and C++ 10-11 (there was no C++ 7-9), `CodeGear\BDS\#.#` for Delphi/C++ 12-14, `Embarcadero\BDS\#.#` for Delphi/C++ 15 onwards.